# How to get Jenkins Build details like build number and test result status of a particular GitHub commit

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-api

I am working on a POC, where I want to get Jenkins build details like build number, Test result status, build status of a particular number using Git Hub Commitsha number.

Can someone let me know if there is any GitHub API that can be use to fetch details from Jenkins with GitHub commit sha id.

Comment: GitHub API to the best of my knowledge knows nothing about Jenkins. You can do that by storing the relevant information (sha + build number or link + test result) from each build.

Comment: Is there any jenkins api where we can get build number and test result using commit sha id

Comment: There isn't. As mentioned, you can store this off Jenkins.